# Add elements in for loop to a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have multiple canvas elements:

```
<canvas class="screen" width="250" height="250" data-json="{{json_encode($board)}}"></canvas>
```

In my javascript I do the following:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('screen');
for (var i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
    var podium = new Image();
    podium.canvas = canvas[i];
    podium.onload = function() {
        var coordinates = JSON.parse(podium.canvas.getAttribute('data-json');
        console.log(coordinates);
        //Later on I add more images or anything else based on coordinates.
    }
    podium.src = 'my_podium_image.jpg';

}
```

But `coordinates` always contains the data from the last `<canvas>` element in my HTML.

However if I put `var coordinates = JSON.parse(podium.canvas.getAttribute('data-json');` outside `onload` and print the output, it prints the data-json attributes from every `canvas` which is correct, but in the `load()` function it's still logs only the last canvas' data attribute. (Multiple times, because of the `for` loop)

I have no idea what's going. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is about Javascript Clousure 
[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

when that function is executed, the value of `podium` is the last one that was assigned.

You should use a selfexecuted function that keeps the scope of `podium`

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('screen');
for (var i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
    (function(podium) {
        podium.canvas = canvas[i];
        podium.onload = function() {
            var coordinates = JSON.parse(podium.canvas.getAttribute('data-json'));
            console.log(coordinates);
            //Later on I add more images or anything else based on coordinates.
        }
        podium.src = 'my_podium_image.jpg';
    })(new Image())

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('screen');

for (var i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    var podium = new Image();
    podium.canvas = canvas[i];
    podium.onload = function() {
    var coordinates = JSON.parse(podium.canvas.getAttribute('data-json');
    console.log(coordinates);

    //Later on I add more images or anything else based on coordinates.
    podium.src = 'my_podium_image.jpg';
  }(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because "onload" event is asynchronous when it got fired your loop already reached the end